# What is the meaning of "someone runs down the tree"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, questions

I would like to know if the phrase "someone runs down the tree" has the meaning of someone who comes down from the top of a tree to the floor in a hurry?
Is it right? If yes, can I use this every time that someone needs to come down from a place in a hurry (running) ?

Thank you all.

Comment: I would assume it's a metaphor, drawing on the image of a squirrel or similar animal running down a tree trunk.  Without some context it's impossible to say, however.

Comment: Let me give an example from a very known story.  Jack and the beanstalk.  When Jack is going to climb down the beanstalk to scape from the giant who was running after him, the phrase says "he(Jack) ran down the beanstalk and reached home".

Comment: What's your audience?  The story of Jack and the Beanstalk is not told that much anymore.

Comment: I am studying English from it and other storys, since I am a non-native speaker and I am still a beginner learner.

Comment: Then note that many versions of the story would use archaic language.

Comment: Oh ok, Got it. But let me give another example then. Someone is upstairs and he hears someone knoking on the door. So he wants to answer the door in a hurry, then "he runs down the stairs" to answer the door. Does this example have the meaning of coming downstairs in a hurry to open the door?

Comment: Yes, that would be fairly idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone is upstairs and he hears someone knoking on the door. So he
> wants to answer the door in a hurry, then "he runs down the stairs" to
> answer the door. Does this example have the meaning of coming
> downstairs in a hurry to open the door?

It is possible to run down stairs. It is possible to run down a hill.  If you are a human, you can not run down a tree - only squirrels can do that.

For humans, running means that you balance on your legs in an almost upright position and move your legs rapidly along a surface.  To descend rapidly from a tree you have two options (1) you jump (2) you climb down the tree quickly.

---

In response to "Jack and the Beanstalk"

**This Jack is running down the beanstalk**
[image]

**This Jack is climbing down the beanstalk**
[image]

Comment: Oh ok, Understood. I have only given the example of the tree. Because of the story of Jack and the beanstalk when he runs down the beanstalk to scape from the giant who was running after him. But the meaning I wanted to know is that, you run down the stairs, run down the hill.. etc. That's it. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Do you have a link to the beanstalk story.  Maybe the beanstalk is arranged like a staircase?

Comment: I don't have it, it's from a course of English I do, where we learn thought short stories, this method is very cool by the way, you learn naturally. But coming back to the point, in the story has others phrases where it says he climbed up the beanstalk, climbed down the beanstalk.. so I think the author have used the phrase "he(Jack) ran down the beanstalk and reached home" to give the idea that he climbed down the beanstalk in a hurry, because the giant was running after him. I don't know if a make myself understandable. If not, I will try explain again. Thank you for your support

Comment: Oh, I've seen and it made it very clear now, so the meaning of run down in this case is he running downwards throught the beanstalk, right?

Comment: It all depends on the shape of the beanstalk in the story-teller's imagination!  If the storyteller imagines that the beanstalk is like a steep road, then Jack can run on it. If the storyteller thinks the beanstalk is like a vertical tree then Jack cannot run, he can only climb.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for clearifiyng it. I appreciated it.